# TFS Change git server destination

Tags: git, tfs

I'm new with TFS and GIT and I'm trying to configure my server.

The problem is that my TFS server machine doesn't have enough space for all my source code. Can I configure TFS to create git repositories in another machine or disk?  I don't find the option to do that in the Team Foundation Server Administration Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TFS can only handle repositories that exist in a single location, you can't have Team Projects in different physical locations.

TFS is built on 2 tiers: **Application** and **Data**.  The Data tier (which is the one you're concerned with at the moment) is handled by an MS SQL server.

You have 2 options:

1. Install SQL Server on another machine that has more space and point your Application tier there instead.
2. The best of all worlds, however, would be to use [Visual Studio Online](https://www.visualstudio.com/), it's free as long as you have 5 or fewer developers, and you don't have to worry about storage space.

If you're using the free version of TFS, you may not be able to separate the Application and Data tiers (It's been a while since I've had it installed, so I can't remember exactly and my next suggestion makes it irrelevant anyway).

Comment: So, my GIT repo it's created in the MSSQL Machine? Thats an ugly limitation... Thank you!

Comment: Correct.  This is the Installation Guide which talks about what is needed: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd631899(v=vs.120).aspx